# Is there the ability to close stackdriver created incidents via the API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is there the ability to close incidents via the stackdriver API? I don't seem to find this capability, but wondering if someone has found something or a workaround?

Comment: do you mean incidents created based on an alert? Like: if the logs exceed 1 TB, something like that? Could you a pic?

Comment: yes an incident created based on an alert, and if i wanted to manipulate the incident externally outside of stackdriver, looks like its been answered below and you cant manipulate incidents.

Answer (score 1):

You can create and manage monitoring alert policies using the API; however, it is not possible to close incidents through API at this time.

Answer (score 1):

In general, Stackdriver alerts are open as long as the policy (really, the condition within the policy) is firing, and close automatically afterward. There are some corner cases, such as if a metric stops being written (this happens a lot with agent metrics) - if there are no more metric points, but there was never a point that would cause the incident to close, it'll just sit there for seven days and then close automatically.

The Alerting API lets you modify alerting policies, but it doesn't address alerts at all. There are some upcoming developments around IRM (https://cloud.google.com/incident-response/) that may help, but in general "closing" an alert isn't really a thing that a human does, it's an indication that the problem has gone away.

Aaron Sher, Stackdriver engineer

Comment: Can we reduce/adjust the 7 days?

Comment: There's no user-facing option to do that, sorry.

Comment: There are good reasons to manually closing an incident, one of which is you deployed a bad condition (let's say 1 condition out of 3 was bad). If you remove the condition there is no way to close an incident. Just let devops close the incident and if it happens again then just create a new incident. The current way is too limited.